# Soft version of NoScript

Tags: firefox, web, javascript, noscript

I'm looking for a soft version of NoScript, by which I mean a Firefox extension that blocks most of the usual crap such as google analytics, without blocking unknown stuff by default. Basically I'm looking for a version of no script that blocks only known bad/useless stuff, and that almost never requires user interaction.

EDIT: my goal here is browser speed, **not** security. (Although security can be a nice side-effect)

EDIT: Yescript is not what I'm looking for either, because it doesn't come with a default blacklist, so you need to add things manually. Not very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) ,

> Ghostery alerts you about the web
>   bugs, ad networks and widgets on every
>   page on the web.
>
> Web bugs are hidden scripts that track
>   your behavior and are used by the
>   sites you visit to understand their
>   own audience.

Answer (score 6):

There is [YesScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4922), which is basically blacklists instead of whitelists stuff.

Comment: Also SomeScript (http://tunginobi.spheredev.org/site/node/71) which is discontinued for its limitedness, but useful.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for a "magic wand". :-)

Seriously, that's not what NoScript is for. To get that kind of behaviour, I suggest turning off NoScript entirely and using AdBlockPlus to block the "usual crap".

**EDIT:** If your goal is browser speed, then any kind of extension at all that blocks URLs will speed up your browsing, because less bytes have to be downloaded. If you are thinking of "bloated" extensions that connect to update servers to download new configurations, then just turn off that option.

Comment: ABP won't block google analytics.

Comment: I always configure ABP to block google analytics, and it's always blocked it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in security or "more or less security"?

If you're interested in security (usually when you are in control of your machine), in this scenario, nothing beats NoScript IMHO. YesScript is an alternative, but:

> Unlike NoScript, **YesScript does**
>   **absolutely nothing to improve your**
>   **security.** I believe that Firefox is
>   secure enough by default and that
>   blocking all scripts by default is
>   paranoia. YesScript strives to remove
>   hassles from your browsing experience,
>   rather than add them.

This is from the YesScript official add-on Mozilla's website. And I don't think "Firefox is secure by default". Blocking all scripts by default isn't paranoia. To have a really secure environment you block suspicious **behaviors** so they won't use a possible exploit that wasn't fixed.

If you're interested in a "more or less security" - suppose a machine with a non technical person using it - I suggest using [WOT](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3456). You can try YesScript too. But remember it can be more secure.

When I started using NoScript, I thought it was a pain because EVERY website I was using, it was blocking javascripts. But you get ussed to it, and after 2 years using this extension, you get used to it.

For tech users, I don't think there's better approach then NoScript, ABP and WOT extensions together.

Comment: I'm not interested in security, I'm interested in browser speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can just black list certain things but allow everything else in NoScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could just download one of the many whitelists that NoScript provides and import it into NoScript.

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to block web analytics, I would recommend AdBlock Plus, with the EasyPrivacy filter set.

I learned of that particular filter from the EFF's [Stop Online Tracking Tutorial](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/04/4-simple-changes-protect-your-privacy-online), which has other suggestions I highly recommend, though they're not limited to just stopping analytics.

Answer (score -1):

Since your goal here is browser speed and not security I would recommend Ad-Block.

Maybe include the WOT extension can improve on that by giving some degree of security.

Comment: do **NOT install WOT**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html