# Firefox NoScript: How to block only one particular domain?

Tags: firefox, noscript, blacklist

I started using the Firefox extension NoScript, but I'd like to allow all scripts by default, only one particular domain (google-analytics.com) should be blocked/blacklisted.

Is that possible? I could figure out only the other way around: It disables everything by default, but allows a few pages from a whitelist; but this behavior makes the web pretty unusable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this solution was possible by the time the question was asked. However, under 'options' there are 3 standard setting: 'default', 'trusted' and 'untrusted'. 'Default' is what every website gets by default. Activate that tab and now you can tick everything you want to allow. To blacklist websites, switch them to 'untrusted'.
[Edit: Added a screen shot to clarify the point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp6KK.png)

Comment: 7 year old question! Good Necro, man.The first part of the question is about allowing all by default. Your answer doesn't explain that part. I would suggest using a different plugin. There are plenty of ones for blocking simple stuff like this.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker. Allowing all by default is done by modifying the 'default' setting: Just tick everything 'script', 'object', 'media', 'frame' etc.

Comment: Ok. He is asking for a way to set something like "Allow all on this page" on every page by default. This is called "blacklisting". NoScript is a "whitelisting" program. It does the opposite of what he wants. Blacklisting is not effective security. He should use a different plugin or use this one properly.

Answer (score 2):

NoScript allows blacklisting.
Just select "Allow script globally (dangerous)", then use "Forbid google-analytics.com".

Comment: This is a secondary solution. It would be great to find a direct solution. Blacklist google-analytics.com - that is. So the statement *NoScript allows blacklisting* is exaggeration because it does not do it explicitly.

Comment: Doesn't work in current version of Noscript. By checking "Disable restrictions globally" you lose ability to use per-site permissions. Meaning that you allow everything without exceptions, when using this checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think NoScript allows you to blacklist.

If you click the NoScript icon in the bottom-right you can whitelist domains as you go. Just pop up the menu and click "allow" (not "temporarily allow"). There's also an "Allow all this page" option here as well.

This is the safest option, as you're protected against every domain you've not visited - instead of just *one* you're trying to blacklist; there's plenty of other tracking and malicious domains out there you probably want protection from as well.

Alternatively, check out the question [Soft version of NoScript?](https://superuser.com/questions/74310/soft-version-of-noscript), which offers some alternative options to achieve what you're after (but potentially without the security gains).

Comment: Current version of NoScript allows blacklisting, see this answer https://superuser.com/a/1299617/949706